# Fixing thread-unsafe function

Tags: concurrency

My textbook, Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective, give the following as an example of a thread-unsafe function:

```
unsigned int next = 1;

int rand () {
    next = next * W + X;
    return (unsigned int)(next/Y) % Z;
}

void srand (unsigned int seed) {
    next = seed;
}
```

The book says the **only** way to fix this function is to rewrite it so that's it's reentrant. I'm having a hard time seeing why you can't just synchronize writes to next using a mutex. I can see why this wouldn't be advisable if you have lots of threads. But I still, in terms of correctness, shouldn't that work?

Answer (score 0):

Your fix is probably not the best way to do things.  For example, one thread could get switched out after reading `next` but before writing it, and a second thread could get switched in and call the function multiple times, advancing through the pseudorandom series by a number of iterations.  Then when the first thread is switched back in, it writes its now stale value to `next`, 'backing up' the pseudorandom sequence from the standpoint of the second thread.

Now, if that kind of behavior is acceptable for your purposes, then simply protecting the write of `next` with a mutex would work - but in that case, it would also meet the definition of 'making the function reentrant'.